# Multiple "cannot be resolved or is not a field" in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a code for grocery shopping but the very first part I worked on got me confused. Even though I'm sure name, price, and taxable are already declared, and it works with this.xxx. For some reason obj.xxx doesn't register. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
public class GroceryItem {
    
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private boolean taxable;
 
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        
        return (this.name==obj.name && this.price==obj.price && this.taxable==obj.taxable); //fields after obj aren't working, ex) this.name is fine but obj.name isn't
        
    }
    public String toString() {
        
        String taxableStr = String.valueOf(taxable);
        return String.format("%s: %.2f: %s", name, price, taxableStr);
        
    }
 
}
```

Comment: I doubt `Object` has the attributes like `taxable` you are trying to get.

Comment: The class object doesn't have feilds `taxable`, `name`, `price`. To use it you will have to typecast that object into class`GroceryItem`

Comment: Also You are comparing two strings using `==` which will check that the reference of the two strings is same or not. You should use equals() method when comparing the string

Answer (score 1):

Object class does not have attributes you are trying to get.

If you want to compare two classes of the same type (class), you need to cast it first:

```
GroceryItem castedObj = (GroceryItem) obj;
```

Ideally, check if the obj is instance of the required class before casting (using `instanceof`)

Answer (score 1):

The `Object` class does not contain the fields `name`, `price` and `taxable`. To compare these fields you can typecast the object to `GroceryItem` class.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){
  if (!(obj instanceof GroceryItem)) { 
      return false; 
  } 
  GroceryItem grocery = (GroceryItem) obj; 
  return (this.name.equals(grocery.name) && this.price == grocery.price && this.taxable == grocery.taxable); 
        
}
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you!

Followup question, since obj is not the class, wouldn't instanceof always return false?

Comment: Object is the base class and every class extends the base Object class. Since all the classes extends the Object class, thus passing a instance of GroceryItem to the equals function won't throw an type error. Now the obj instance can belong be of any class.The instance of will check the type of the instance, if it is instance of GroceryItem then the instance of will return true.

Comment: Upvoted both for correctness and for fixing the comparison of `name`.